# Cant find CPOS80250 Linux Drivers .ppd

Tags: raspbian, printers, thermal-printer, cups, ppd

I recently bought the CPOS80250 thermal printer but cant find the linux drivers. I am trying to install it on a raspberry pi 2 but cant find the ppd file anywhere. Anyone with leads?

Answer (score 0):

```
//For basic printing you do not need driver
//--------------------------------------------
std::ofstream osFD;
osFD.open("/dev/usb/lp0",std::ofstream::out);
osFD << "Hello My Printer";
```